# How to handle bigger length of random string in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Need to post a payload from Jmeter with the following format,

Sample HTTP Payload:

```
[
  {
    "audit": {
        "id": "${id}",
        "timestamp": "${time}",
        "type": "input",
        "entry": "File retrieved, validated and processed successfully",
        "message": {
          "headers": "${headrer_payload}",
          "payload": "${message_payload}",
          "type": "csv",
          "protocol": ""
        },
        "keys": [
          {
            "name": "file-archive-location",
            "value": "Performance Test From Jmeter"
          }
        ]
      },
      "context": {
        "transactionId": "${trans_id}",
        "messageId": "${messageid}",
        "customerId": "Test",
        "studyId": "TEST1234"
      }
    },
    "dataVersion": "1.0",
    "metadataVersion": "1"
  }
]
```

here for headrer_payload & message_payload I am using the Jmeter random function within a JSR223 preprocessor with a length as follow,

```
def header = "${__RandomString(30500,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890=,)}"
def payload = "${__RandomString(30500,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890=,)}"

    vars.put("headrer_payload",header);
    vars.put("message_payload",payload);
```

I have a fear when this script will run for longer time there is a heap space crunch for JMeter. Is there any better way to handle such a large string? Cannot reduce the length.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables into Groovy scripts](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), you can insert JMeter Functions directly into [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler's "Body Data" area:

```
[
  {
    "audit": {
        "id": "${__UUID}",
        "timestamp": "${time}",
        "type": "input",
        "entry": "File retrieved, validated and processed successfully",
        "message": {
          "headers": "${__RandomString(30500,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890=,)}",
          "payload": "${__RandomString(30500,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890=,)}",
          "type": "csv",
          "protocol": ""
        },
        "keys": [
          {
            "name": "file-archive-location",
            "value": "Performance Test From Jmeter"
          }
        ]
      },
      "context": {
        "transactionId": "${__UUID}",
        "messageId": "${__UUID}",
        "customerId": "Test",
        "studyId": "TEST1234"
      }
    },
    "dataVersion": "1.0",
    "metadataVersion": "1"
  }
]
```

Moreover, given you ticked "Cache compiled script" box it means that the same value will be used for all subsequent iterations instead of generating a new one.

Injecting the functions into HTTP Request sampler body will allow you to avoid saving 60 kilobytes of data in JMeter Variables so heap usage will be less by that factor.

In general you can have 2 GB strings without any issues given they fit into your JVM Heap and in any case it's is possible to allocate more heap to JMeter as long as you have enough RAM, see [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for more details.